# What could be observed with LOFAR in 230 MHz - 10.0 MHz wavelength?

Tags: observational-astronomy, astrophysics, radio-astronomy, resource-request, lofar

Nuclear astrophysics greatly interests me and i was wondering if there is something that could be observed with the LOFAR project in this wavelength that would benefit the field?

Also some general information about this wavelength in astronomy or pointers to information sources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to google the science case for LOFAR then...